# Linking data extensions in Contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I'll use a similar example to what we have in real life. Let's say I would like to link 2 data extensions in Contact Builder which have 3 identical database fields, and a few different ones. Namely,

```
DATA EXTENSION 1: PRODUCT REVIEWS:
SubscriberKey 
OrderNumber
ProductNumber
ProductReviewed
ReviewScore
-----------------------------------------
DATA EXTENSION 2: ORDER DETAILS
SubscriberKey
OrderNumber
ProductNumber
PurchaseDate
```

Can I link the 2 DATA EXTENSIONS just on the SubscriberKey as unique identifier, or must I use a combined primary key and map all the identical fields?
In general, in cases where we have identical fields in two data extensions we'd like to link in Contact Builder, do we always have to map all the identical fields or just a PK such as SAP account number?

Comment: I would say that would depend on your data and how granular it gets in the associated relational tables. In general though, it is best practice to link any and all shared pkeys to ensure everything is as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Linking Data Extensions in Contact Builder is no different than doing general data modeling outside. You can link on any number of fields depending upon your data and requirements.

You can only join one DE with All Contacts and the recommendation is use ContactKey with your Subscriber. After that is done, other DEs can be joined with that first DE. Type of relationship and the fields is totally up to your requirements

Hope that helps